# How to prevent GreyStripe Fullscreen Ad from dismissing my modal view controller landing page?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I'm landing a GreyStripe Fullscreen Ad in a modal view controller in my iPhone app. The problem is that when GreyStripe SDK dismisses the full screen Ad, it also dismisses my modal view controller.

Comment: can you post some code so at least we will know exact problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find a reasonable way of solving this problem, and instead of presenting my landing page as a modal view controller I presented it the classic way in a navigation controller. This solved my problem.

Comment: I'm having this same problem. I tried presenting as a push instead of modal and it works fine unless you click the advert to see the web content, then on close it dismisses my modal view again!