# Presenting modalViewController is dealloc'ing the one calling it

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I'm having a few problems integrating Greystripe adverts (documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477261/greystripe-sdk-full-screen-ads-removing-modal-view-controller) but not important). A way around my problem if to just present my gameView like this

```
iSlideAppDelegate *appDelegate = (iSlideAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
            Game3ViewController *gameView = (Game3ViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainGameController"];
            [appDelegate.window addSubview:gameView.view];
```

This is basically just adding my gameView on top of the current view controller.

Now from this view I want to show another modal view like this

```
FullScreenSelfAdViewController *adView = [[FullScreenSelfAdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FullScreenSelfAdViewController" bundle:nil];
        [adView setDismissDelegate:self];
        [self presentModalViewController:adView animated:YES];
```

The problem is, when this view is displayed, my gameView deallocates. Meaning when I call to dismiss the AdView it dealloc's but stays on screen as the underlying gameView isn't there any more.

Is there a better way to call these views? (I can't call my gameView by presenting it as a modal view).
Or a way to keep the gameView from deallocating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to guess, you don't have a strong variable retaining the class that gets dealloced. Whoever creates that class should have a strong ivar doing so. I had this exact same problem when I tried to create an object and use it without retaining it. Note that for UIAlerts, the system retains it when you call [alert show], leading to think you can do this with other view controllers (which you cannot!)

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you. Creating a strong variable worked. It's funny how you overlook the things you spend most of your time doing.

Comment: Hah ask me how I knew the answer:-)

Comment: I'm guessing hours trying to figure out why something won't retain. Lol